# Erro no retorno de dados do php no ionic

Tags: php, ionic

Estou fazendo uma app em ionic em que eu coloco o cep em um campo e o backend me retorna todos os outros dados, como estado, cidade, logradouro... Porém algo estranho acontece, ele retorna toda a estrutura do php e não os dados que deveriam vir.
Fiz uma aplicação teste, na web, que funciona, só no ionic que está dando esse problema.

Segue o erro no console:
[image: print]

angular:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('enderecoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.pegaCep = function () {
        //console.log($scope.endereco.cep);
        $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).then(function (endereco){
        console.log(endereco);

        });
     }
})
```

php:

```
<?php

include('correios.class.php');

$cep = $_GET['cep'];

if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
    $correios = Correios::cep($_GET['cep']);
    $correios = json_encode($correios[0]);
        die($correios);
}elseif(isset($_GET['codigo_rastreio'])){
    die(json_encode(Correios::rastreio($_GET['codigo_rastreio'])));
}else{
    die('informe parametro GET cep ou codigo_rastreio');
}

?>
```

Print aba Network do console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código de como você se comunica com o backend

Comment: Como está seu código ? Posta aí o `PHP` que retorna esses dados.

Comment: A extensão do arquivo está .PHP?

Comment: Pelo visto o PHP não foi executado, foi enviado o raw do código fonte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque assim no lugar do $http.get

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/ionic/vcApp/www/php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep)
```

Do jeito que você fez, o PHP não está sendo compilado pois não tem um WebServer para compilar o mesmo. No caso do jeito que você fez, estava acessando o arquivo .php diretamente.

Abraços!

Comment: Se eu não colocar entre " " o endereço http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/ionic/vcApp/www/php/pegaCep.php?cep=" dai não funciona

Comment: Ops, erro meu! deve colocar o link entre ""

Answer (score 0):

Tira o `die()` como retorno de função e usa o próprio `return`.

```
if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
    $correios = Correios::cep($_GET['cep']);
    $correios = json_encode($correios[0]);
}elseif(isset($_GET['codigo_rastreio'])){
    $dados = Correios::rastreio($_GET['codigo_rastreio']);
    $correios = json_encode($dados);
}else{
   $correios = 'informe parametro GET cep ou codigo_rastreio';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
return $correios;
```

---

Debaixo do `include` faça uma verificação e veja se existe a função `json_encode` no servidor. Faça assim:

```
if (function_exists('json_encode')) {
    echo 'Existe';
} else {
    echo 'Não Existe';
}

die();
```

Veja o que retorna na aba `Network > XHR` no Inspect Element.

---

No código do `Angular` tente assim:

```
$http.get($http({method: 'GET', url: "php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep,  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}}).success(function(endereco){
    console.log(endereco);
});
```

Comment: Continua o problema...

Comment: Coloca return em todos o q? Em todos os die()?

Comment: Nada, o problema continua.

Comment: Acredito que no 1o. pois eu passo o cep.

Comment: Diz que existe json_encode

Comment: Beleza. Alterei meu código no POST, veja agora. Adicionei o `header`. Veja que alterei o código final nos `ifs`.

Comment: Nada, continua mostrado todo o php

Comment: Coloquei no meu post um print da aba Network do console.

Comment: Alterei o código do Angular, veja.

Comment: Agora ta dando erro no app e não no php

Comment: Qual erro está dando ?

Comment: Abre todo desconfigurado